# design an extendable database model

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, database-design

Currently I'm doing a project whose specifications are unclear - well who doesn't. I wonder what's the best development strategy to design a DB, that's going to be extended sooner or later with additional tables and relations. I want to include "changeability".

My main concern is that I want to apply design patterns (it's a university project) and I want to separate the constant factors from those, that change by choosing appropriate design patterns - in my case MVC and a set of sub-patterns at model level.
When it comes to the DB however, I may have to resdesign my model in my MVC approach, because my domain model at a later stage my require a different set of classes representing the DB tables. I use Hibernate as an abstraction layer between DB and application.

Would you start with a very minimal DB, just a few tables and relations? And what if I want an efficient DB, too? I wonder what strategies are applied in the real world. Stakeholder analysis for example isn't a sufficient planing solution when it comes to changing requirements. I think - at a DB level - my design pattern ends. So there's breach whose impact I'd like to minimize with a smart strategy.

Comment: Remember Brian Kernighan's rule: "Make it right before you make it faster."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a simple answer: BE MINIMALISTIC.

Try to figure out the main entities. Don´t worry about the properties, you will fill them later. Then, create the relations between the entities. Create a test application using wour favorite ORM (Hibernate?), build some unit tests, and voilà, you have your minimal DB operational. :)

Answer (score 4):

In unclear situations I prefer a minimalistic DB design, supporting the needs known right now. My experience is that any effort to be clever, to model for future needs makes the model more complex. When the new needs arise, they are often in unforseen areas. The extra modeling for future needs doesn't fit the new needs, but rather makes the needed refactoring even harder.

As you already have chosen Hibernate to be able to decouple the DB design and the OO model, I think that sticking with an as simple DB as possible is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

What you describe is typical for almost every project. There are a few things you can do however.

Try to isolate the concepts (not their realizations) of your problem domain. Remember: Extending a data model is almost always easy (add a new table, a new column etc.) but changing your data model is hard and requires data migration.

I advocate using an Agile development process: Implement only what you need right now, but make sure you understand the complete problem before modeling it.

Another thing you should check before starting to hack away your code is wether your chosen infrastructure is appropriate. Using a relational database when you want to change your schema's very often is usually a bad match. Document databases are schema-less and hence more flexible. I think you should evaluate wether using a relational database is really appropriate for you application.

Answer (score 3):

"Currently I'm doing a project whose specifications are unclear"

Given the 'database' tag, I assume you are asking this question in a *database* context.

Remember that a database is a set of *ASSERTIONS OF FACT* (capitalization intended).

If it is unclear what kind of "assertions of fact" your user wants to be registered by the database, then you simply cannot define (the structure of) your database.

And you will be helping both yourself and your user by first trying to clear out everything that is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

No project begins with requirements entirely known and fixed for all time. Use an agile, iterative approach to the database design so you that you can accommodate change during development.

All database designs are extensible and subject to change during their lifetime. Don't try to avoid change. Just make sure you have the right people and processes in place to manage change effectively when it happens.